# Must fully qualify resources in jar

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

When I use the pre-built jar from the osmdroid website in my project, everything works as expected. However, if I create my own jar from the osmdroid source, I get "Resource not found" errors (marker_default.png, etc.). I changed

```
final String resName = pResId.name() + ".png";
```

to

```
final String resName = "/resources/org/osmdroid/" + pResId.name() + ".png";
```

in DefaultResourceProxyImpl.java:getBitmap

and then it works correctly. Is there something I can do in my export jar process that will not require me to change this line?

Comment: Put the resource at the root of your jar.

Comment: What are you using to create the jar from source?

Comment: @kurtzmarc Eclipse - right click on the project -> export -> Jar

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The resource exists in the jar at resources/org/osmdroid/. How would I change this location during the export?

Comment: Can you try [Maven](https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/wiki/HowToMaven)? That is the preferred way to build the jar now.